# What is the exact solution of using Tailwind 2 with Angular 11? I am just tired of finding proper solution. Nothing really works

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, sass, tailwind-css

I have tried a lot in last couple of weeks. I have wasted too much time to figure out. But, I am failed to find solution. Please help me.

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(customWebpackConfig).
```

This is the error I am facing now.

I have imported Tailwind properly.

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

This is the `package.json`. I have tried by downgrade the postcss, postcss-loader. Nothing works.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^11.0.0-beta.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.2.1",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-scss": "^3.0.4",
    "sass": "^1.27.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.1",
  }
```

This is the `webpack.config.js` file

```
let sass;
try {
  sass = require('node-sass');
} catch {
  sass = require('sass');
}

module.exports = {
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                ident: 'postcss',
                syntax: 'postcss-scss',
                plugins: [
                  "postcss-import",
                  "tailwindcss",
                  "autoprefixer"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              implementation: sass,
              sourceMap: false,
              sassOptions: {
                precision: 8
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Check this https://github.com/ngneat/tailwind

Comment: Your issue seems to be in angular.json..?

Comment: @Chellappanவ I am trying. Hope for the best.

Comment: @MikeOne I am trying Chellappan's solution. If it works, I will probably figure the problem out. Will notify. 

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, this is a legit problem.

Comment: Thank you @Arkilo .

I did not find any solution yet.

Comment: @MehediHasanLikhon so I resolved this issue by basically downgrading my version of angular. Instead of using angular 11 I removed angular 11 and installed angular 10. Then I used the ngneat tailwind library Chellappan mentioned above. But it worked like a charm, I would highly suggest downgrading.

Comment: is this helpful https://github.com/ayox/Angular-11-tailwindcss-2-starter for you ?

Comment: I always use this `ng add ngx-tailwind` which does all the hard work for you so you can start working with Angular & Tailwind straight away! I found this from https://manuel-rauber.com/2020/12/07/integrate-tailwindcss-with-angular/